# Динамическое задание имен столбцов DBGrid

Tags: ооп, dbgrid, delphi, delphi-7

Написал обработчик события `OnActivated`, в котором по именам созданных компонентов
образуются названия столбцов `DBGrid`

```
procedure TfmTableData.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var openTable : TTableSpec;
    CountColumns : integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  openTable:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.Listbox1.Items.Strings[fmListOfTables.Listbox1.ItemIndex]));
  CountColumns:=openTable.Fields.ComponentCount;
  //DBGrid1.Columns.:=CountColumns;
  for I := 0 to CountColumns-1 do
      begin
        DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title:=TColumnTitle(openTable.Fields.Components[i].Name);
      end;
end;
```

Но на строке

```
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title:=TColumnTitle(openTable.Fields.Components[i].Name);
```

выдает ошибку

```
Access violation at address 0040842 in module 'GuUI.exe'. Read of address FFFCD2E8.
```

Comment: @_perchuk, спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пытаетесь привести `string` (он же `TComponentName`) к типу `TColumnTitle`.

Попробуйте `DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption := openTable.Fields.Components[i].Name`;